How to arrange objects in groups where arrangement of groups and objects themselves matter?
Consider you have $n$ distinct objects that you want to arrange into $r$ groups. But here is the catch. The group sizes (the number of objects allowed in each group (at least $1$)) are unspecified. And under each group, the arrangement of objects matters. (If a group has (say) $2$ objects and say the elements were $a$ and $b$, then $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ would be $2$ different ways.) After you have assorted objects to all the $r$ groups, the groups themselves can be permuted/arranged among themselves.
Here's my work:

The number of ways to pick $r$ objects from $n$ objects are $\binom{n}{r}$ and the number of ways of arranging these objects among $r$ groups (so at least they have 1) is $\binom{r}{r}r!$
The remaining $n-r$ objects can be arranged in the following method: first object (of the remaining) has $r$ choices, second one too...and so on. By fundamental principele of counting I got the number of ways without group permutations as, $\binom{n}{r}r!\times r^{n-r}$
Now the number of ways to permute $r$ groups are $r!$ and the number of ways become $\binom{n}{r}(r!)^2\times r^{n-r}$

I want to know if I have done the permutations within each groups. And then I'm unsure if I've done it right.
Is there another way to think about it?

Please help guys. I could not find a specific type of textbook explanation to refer. I am new to stackexchage (noob).

Welcome to this forum. You are required to show some effort first. You can try with a small example, e.g. groups of $2,2,3,4$ from $11$ distinct objects, for groups labeled $A,B,C,D$ and edit in  your effort, and where you are facing difficulty.

Can you give an example, say with the three objects $a,b,c$ and two "groups" (perhaps ordered sets) so we know what you are counting and what not?  You say you would count $(a,b),(c)$ and $(b,a),(c)$ as different, but would $(c),(a,b)$  also count as different and   would $(a,b,c),(,)$ count at all?

@trueblueanil, surely I will show in a while...

@MikeEarnest No. None groups can be empty.

Isn't the answer just $n!\binom{n-1}{r-1}$? Arrange objects in $n!$ ways, then place $r-1$ dividers between some of the objects.

Hey guys, I have clarified my subject more... And showed how i worked it out! Please now share your ideas by an answer :)

@zetazero, Thank you for tha answer. It is correct

I am turning zeta zero’s comment into an answer.
The number of ways is $$n!\binom{n-1}{r-1}.$$
You have $n$ distinct objects. Start by arranging these in a row, in $n!$ ways. There are $n-1$ gaps between adjacent objects. Select $r-1$ of these gaps, in $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ ways, and place a divider in each gap. These $r-1$ dividers break the line of objects into $r$ groups, which is the goal.
This is related to the Lah numbers. If you instead said that the order of the groups did not matter (but the order within each group still matters), then the number of ways would be $\frac{n!}{r!}\binom{n-1}{r-1}$, which is a Lah number.

That is correct
